# If Drach’Nyen exiles a commander and it is put into command zone, does it still get bonus power?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

If [Drach'Nyen](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Drach%27Nyen) exiles a commander and it is put into command zone, does it still get bonus power? I think it is the same as with Mimic vat and it only gives menace then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If Drach'Nyen exiles a commander and it is put in the command zone, Drach'Nyen does not give any bonus power, but it does still grant menace.**

Drach'Nyen's second ability says

> Equipped creature has menace and gets +X/+0, where X is **the exiled card's** power.

The phrase "the exiled card" can only refer to a card in the exile zone. If the card is not in the exile zone, that part of the ability does not work. This is specified in [rule 607.2a](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Linked_abilities):

> If an object has an activated or triggered ability printed on it that instructs a player to exile one or more cards and an ability printed on it that refers either to “the exiled cards” or to cards “exiled with [this object],” these abilities are linked. **The second ability refers only to cards in the exile zone that were put there as a result of an instruction to exile them in the first ability.**

Then [rule 107.2](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Numbers_and_symbols) says

> If anything needs to use a number that can’t be determined, either as a result or in a calculation, it uses 0 instead.

Since the ability can't find the exiled card, it can't determine the power, so it uses 0 instead. The ability still works and still grants menace.